# Having problems with generic types - Java

Tags: java, class, generics, subclass

I have three Classes that all use generic types:

```
public class Animal implements Comparable<Animal>

public class Sequence<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T>

public class Zoo<T extends Animal> extends Sequence<T>
```

So my thought process went like this: `Animal` is a subtype of `Comparable<Animal>`. The generic subtpe T in `Sequence` is also a subtype of `Comparable<Animal>`. Thus, when I create an object of type `Sequence<Animal>`, it works perfectly. But now I created a Class `Zoo`. I want `Zoo` to be the same as `Sequence`, except that the generic Type T should be limited to Animal (and only be able to take one fixed subtype of Animal, or Animal). So I make `Zoo` extend `Sequence<T>`, with T extending `Animal`. I thought that it should work, since `Animal` is a subtype of `Comparable`, but the compiler gives me an error:

> `T is not within its bounds; should implement Comparable<T>`

But T is already implementing Comparable, since it's a subtype of Animal, is it not?
Can somebody explain what's going on, or how I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the bound on `Sequence`'s type variable:

```
public class Sequence<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

or, define `Zoo` without a type variable:

```
public class Zoo extends Sequence<Animal>
```